# Java web crawling - static URLS

Tags: java, web-crawler, data-mining

I'm going to look a bit more into the techniques because obviously there is a lot to learn but I was wondering what the best approach to handling static URLs is. I would guess it has to do with cookies but I'm not positive.

E.x. So I search my query on a site `example.com`, `example.com/search?string=blah` then sends me to a url that is specific to the search string. From there I can then go further (to the data I actually want) but the link to the results is a static URL `example.com/results.php?id=33`, the id stays the same regardless of search string. So the only logical thing is a cookie being passed right? If so, how would I have Java open a connection, grab the cookies, then open a new connection and pass the cookies? I tried something like this with two methods, one that opens the initial connection and grabs the cookies then opens a new connection and passes the cookies to that method.

There are definitely multiple cookies if that helps.

Also, any links/resources that you think I might find helpful would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not necessarily a cookie - the id=33 could be all the server needs to remember that that particular query was.

Comment: But how does it associate multiple values with that 33 and where is the value stored? Because if the id was all it needed, why is it the same for every query?

Comment: Ok so i think I narrowed the problem down to that of authentication, how would I authenticate using a login and pw?